# no me aparece Locale.SPAIN

Tags: android, android-studio

quiero mostrar el nombre del mes en un recycler view, pero no encuentro la opcion Locale.SPAIN, y lo tengo que mostrar en ingles.
este es el comando del adapter que tiene que mostrar el mes:

```
holder.toma.setText("Mes: "+ getMonthName(listDatos.get(position).getMes(), Locale.US, false));
```

y esta la funcion getMonthName:

```
private String getMonthName(final int index, final Locale locale, final boolean shortName)
{
    String format = "%tB";

    if (shortName)
        format = "%tb";

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, index);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    return String.format(locale, format, calendar);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para crear una configuración regional para idioma Español debes usar:

```
Locale spanish = new Locale("es", "ES");
```

ejemplo:

```
Locale locale =  new Locale("es", "ES");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
```

ya que actualmente las constantes que existen para crear configuraciones usando la clase [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) son únicamente:

```
CANADA  
Constante útil para el país.
CANADA_FRENCH   
Constante útil para el país.
CHINA   
Constante útil para el país.
CHINESE 
Constante útil para el lenguaje.
ENGLISH 
Constante útil para el lenguaje.
FRANCE  
Constante útil para el país.
FRENCH  
Constante útil para el lenguaje.
GERMAN  
Constante útil para el lenguaje.
GERMANY 
Constante útil para el país.
ITALIAN 
Constante útil para el lenguaje.
ITALY   
Constante útil para el país.
JAPAN   
Constante útil para el país.
JAPANESE    
Constante útil para el lenguaje.
KOREA   
Constante útil para el país.
KOREAN  
Constante útil para el lenguaje.
PRC 
Constante útil para el país.
PRIVATE_USE_EXTENSION   
La clave para la extensión de uso privado ('x').
ROOT    
Useful constant for the root locale.
SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE  
Constante útil para el lenguaje.
TAIWAN  
Constante útil para el país.
TRADITIONAL_CHINESE 
Constante útil para el lenguaje.
UK  
Constante útil para el país.
UNICODE_LOCALE_EXTENSION    
La clave para la extensión de configuración regional Unicode ('u').
US  
Constante útil para el país.
```

---

En el caso de tu código puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
//holder.toma.setText("Mes: "+ getMonthName(listDatos.get(position).getMes(), Locale.US, false));
holder.toma.setText("Mes: "+ getMonthName(listDatos.get(position).getMes(), new Locale("es", "ES"), false));
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me ha funcionado.

Comment: Excelente @guillanBesada , saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que España no es tan guay ;)

Al menos para el desarrollo de Java y [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) y por eso deberías revisar siempre la documentación oficial. Sólo hay unos pocos Locale preconstruidos que usan nombres de países (China, US, UK, FRANCE, JAPAN, TAIWAN).

Para los demás, hay que usar los códigos de IDIOMA y PAÍS para construir el locale. Digamos, algo como `new Locale("es", "ES")`